# How to count sum total in Java using Android Studio

Tags: java, android, string, sum

I just learned Java using Android Studio.

My code error for use integer to count sum.

I try to decode string to integer but still error.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edtvalue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.value);
        final Spinner edtjw = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        txtpa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pa);
        txttotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);

        btncount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String value = edtvalue.getText().toString().trim();
                String jw = edtjw.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();

                double h = Double.parseDouble(value);
                double j = Double.parseDouble(jw);

                String numbertostring = String.format ("%.2f", (0.02*h));
                String numbertostring2 = String.format ("%.2f", (0.025*h));
                String numbertostring3 = String.format ("%.2f", (0.0275*h));
                if (j == 1){
                    txtpa.setText(numbertostring);
                } else if (j ==2){
                    txtpa.setText(numbertostring);
                } else if (j ==3){
                    txtpa.setText(numbertostring);
                } else if (j ==4){
                    txtpa.setText(numbertostring2);
                } else  if (j ==5){
                    txtpa.setText(numbertostring3);
                } else {
                    txtpa.setText(0);
                }

                int tot = (h*j)+txtpa;
                txttotal.setText("Total : "  + tot);
}}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. You say you get an error, can you tell us what that error is? Please give us as much relevant detail about your issue so that we can help you.

Comment: What error you are getting? Add content of error/exception you are getting.

Comment: I want to add sum from int h, int j, and string txtpa. can you help me?

Comment: try `double total = (h*j) + Double.parseDouble(txtpa.getText().toString());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the code snippet, you should get string value from `txtpa` which is of type `TextView`, then parse it into `double`

`double tot = (h*j)+Double.parseDouble(txtpa.getText().toString());`

as mentioned in the above comment by Naitik Soni.

Comment: tot should be double and not int